# Linux: Finding Processes I Started To Kill Them

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I am programmatically starting several servers in Gnome terminal with each server in its own titled tab:

```
gnome-terminal   \
--tab -t "Server1" -e 'bash -c "export BASH_POST_RC=\"pathtoserver1/server1\"; exec bash"' \
--tab -t "Server2" -e 'bash -c "export BASH_POST_RC=\"pathtoserver2/server2\"; exec bash"' \
--tab -t "Server3" -e 'bash -c "export BASH_POST_RC=\"pathtoserver3/server3\"; exec bash"' \
```

I would also like to make a script to programmatically stop them all.

My problem is that the PS names generated are not unique.

I will get 3 PS names called "bash" and 3 called "java".

I will have other processes, NOT, related to these jobs also called "bash" or "java" that I do NOT want killed.

I do not have the option of changing the code or names of these programs.

Is there any way around this?   Can I change the name of the jobs without changing the programs?

Thanks

Comment: Rather than run (bash -c "somethinghere") you could start a script which writes its own PID to a file. Then to stop them all you have to do is send a sughup to all PIDs in that/those files.  Much like many other programs work.